# Light weight mobile application for android

Tags: android, css, angularjs, html

Light weight android application for low memory device
 below is description for my current hardware and software specification.
 I want to develop application with Angular Js HTML5 but I am confused with framework for Native control, so please give your suggestions:

1. Hardware of Device
   Screen Size : 2.4” (QVGA)
   Form factor: Bar with T9 keypad and 4-way Navkey
   Connectivity : LTE Band 3,5,40
   Speed: LTE Cat4
   OS : Custom
   RAM: 256 MB / 128 MB
   Flash: 512 MB / 2GB
   SD Card: 128 GB
   SIM: Single SIM
   Front Camera: VGA/HD
   Rear Camera: VGA/2MP
   Battery: 2000 –2500
   Bluetooth : 4.1 + BLE
   FM Radio: Integrated
   Audio: 2030 or equivalent loud mono speaker
   MHL support
2. Software 
   PIMS and standard apps (Contacts, Messages, Setting, Camera, Photos, Music, Calendar, FM, Browser, Video, File Manager, Notes, Calculator, Clock)
   FOTA and Subsidy Lock
   VoLTEand Video Calling
   HTML5 platform support with Audio/Video tags to run JioHTML5 apps and popular 3rdparty HTML5 apps.
   Platform adaptation for Native Services integration with HTML5
   Indian regional language support (14 languages including IME)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Ionic + AngularJS for light weight application.

- Ionic provides you mostly all the native feel for both Android & iOS.
- If your target version of android is below 4 then there is no use of
  developing a app with this framework
- My point is in the performance side of mobile application
- There will be some native functionalities which will be supported by
  lower version's of android & ios, There is no other way for solving
  these type of issue's

Hope my answer gave you some idea. Thanks!